# Losing internet after IP switches from valid public IP to a private IP, what could be wrong?

Tags: ip, dhcp, isp, ipv4

Basically I have had to call my ISP around 20 times in the last three weeks about this issue. My internet disconnects and my IP changes from a public IP in a valid range for my ISP to something in the 10.x.x.x range (I looked this up, this ip range is soley for private IP addresses from what I read). They say its my modem, but I have tried three different modems. I have tried bypassing my router, have restarted my modem/router/computers, and still have this issue. My router logs show weird connections (the very first entry was edited by me to keep my real ip out):

```
[Internet connected] IP address: 173.x.x.x (valid IP), Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:24:02
[Internet disconnected] Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:24:02
[Internet connected] IP address: 192.168.100.10, Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:23:32
[Internet disconnected] Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:23:31
[Admin login] from source 192.168.1.3, Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:20:37
[Time synchronized with NTP server] Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:20:01
[Internet connected] IP address: 173.17.237.165, Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:19:51
[Internet disconnected] Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:19:51
[Internet connected] IP address: 192.168.100.10, Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:19:06
[Internet disconnected] Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:19:04
[Internet connected] IP address: 10.140.110.185, Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:16:28
[Internet disconnected] Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:16:27
[LAN access from remote] from 58.253.32.129:8063 to 192.168.1.8:21664, Sunday, Jan 07,2018 19:16:26
```

Does anybody have any ideas why this could be happening? Is there any issue with a computer on my network or something with my ISP? For some reason my ISP is saying that my modem is getting provisioned behind another persons network in a different state and they don't know why. How could this be?

Edit:
Here is the network. ISP -> modem (Motorola MB7220) -> router (NETGEAR N600) -> 1 computer connected to ethernet and Xbox, laptop, cell phones on wifi. The cable from the modem goes into the receiving port on the router (ETHERNET IN or something).

I have tried multiple modems, and bypassing my router, both of which did not work. I have isolated the [LAN access from remote] to my parents laptop, not sure if that is helpful.

Comment: Are the logs _from_ your modem? (i.e. are they the same device or not?) What does your setup look like: `ISP → modem → computer` or `ISP → modem → router → computer`? Where does the other end of the "ISP" wire go?

Comment: Without at least a basic network diagram, it's difficult to say.  Please tell us exactly how the basic equipment is hooked up. i.e. what is plugged in to what ports. Also provide the make and model of each device (modem and router). Don't leave out any details you think are irrelevant.

Comment: @grawity Please check my edit!

Comment: 1) When you talk about "bypassing your router", you connect it like `ISP → modem → computer`, right? 2) Does the _modem_ have its own configuration screen somewhere?

Comment: The access from .32.129 appears to be someone from China getting into the device 192.168.1.8. does that seem suspicious to you? Maybe it's Xbox talking to some gaming contact but that's a total guess as I don't know if that's how that works

Comment: @grawity Yes, when I was bypassing I mean ISP -> modem -> computer. And I was not able to find a configuration page for my modem, however, I have tested three different modems (and one that has worked for years) and the issue persists. Not sure if the modem is the issue.

Comment: If it acts purely as a modem (bridge), then it's the upstream's issue. What kind of connection – cable, DSL, dialup?

Comment: @grawity It is a cable connection. When my IP switches to the private one, my ISP told me that my modem is somehow behind another MAC address (I can post it if needed, not sure if it will help). They told me they won't assign me a static IP (reserved for businesses) and they won't reset my account. They basically don't know what to do.